# Is it possible to work two different javascript queries for different functionality on single HTML section?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have made an HTML section. In this section, I have used two containers in a div tag and made it flex so that the final containers would be visible left and right. In the left container, I made three card from top to bottom, and in the right container, I inserted the three images and made them position absolute, so that it will be on one to another. I have used one JavaScript query so that in 5 seconds intervals other images will be visible and the left should be displayed none. But I want to use one more query, and in that, I want functionality that whenever I hover on any card that card's respective image should be visible. For example, if the second/third image is visible and I hover over the first card then the first image should appear.

```js
var activeImageId = 1;
    var nextImageId = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        nextImageId = nextImageId + 1;

        if (nextImageId < 3) {
            document.getElementById("img" + activeImageId).classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
            document.getElementById("img" + nextImageId).classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
            activeImageId = nextImageId;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("img" + activeImageId).classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
            document.getElementById("img" + nextImageId).classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
            activeImageId = 3;
            nextImageId = 0;
        }
    }, 5000);
    
    
    
    
    
    
    // for first image
    function change1() {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/50k.png";
    }

    function change2() {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "images/50k.png";
    }

    // for second image
    function change3() {
        document.getElementById("img2").src = "images/insta-pic.png";
    }

    function change4() {
        document.getElementById("img2").src = "images/insta-pic.png";
    }

    // for third image
    function change5() {
        document.getElementById("img3").src = "images/stats.png";
    }

    function change6() {
        document.getElementById("img3").src = "images/stats.png";
    }
```

```css
.why-choose-main-container {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-details {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-details .card {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 570px;
        height: 670px;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img.visible {
        display: block;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img.hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="why-choose-main-container">
        <div class="why-choose-details">
            <div class="card" onmouseover="change1()" onmouseout="change2()">
                <h2>why1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card" onmouseover="change3()" onmouseout="change4()">
                <h2>why2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card" onmouseover="change5()" onmouseout="change6()">
                <h2>why3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="why-choose-image">
            <img src="images/50k.png" alt="img1" id="img1" class="visible">
            <img src="images/insta-pic.png" alt="img2" id="img2" class="hidden">
            <img src="images/stats.png" alt="img3" id="img3" class="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution Link

You can my solution working [here on CodePen](https://codepen.io/papapps/pen/GRwaPpW?editors=0011).

### HTML

- Each image uses the `onmouseover` you had but I also added a `onmouseout` to handle leaving.
- Each of the images calls the same JS functions but passes in its id as a parameter

```
<div class="why-choose-main-container">
    <div class="why-choose-details">
        <div class="card" onmouseover="onHover('img1')" onmouseout="onHoverLeave('img1')">
            <h2>why1</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card" onmouseover="onHover('img2')" onmouseout="onHoverLeave('img2')">
            <h2>why2</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card" onmouseover="onHover('img3')" onmouseout="onHoverLeave('img3')">
            <h2>why3</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="why-choose-image">
        <img src="images/50k.png" alt="img1" id="img1" class="visible">
        <img src="images/insta-pic.png" alt="img2" id="img2" class="hidden">
        <img src="images/stats.png" alt="img3" id="img3" class="hidden">
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

- The timer function keeps track of the active image but only shows it when the hovering effect is not active
- `onHover` is called whenever the `mouseover` event is called which calls `showHoverImage`, a function that hides the active image and shows the hovered image
- `onHoverLeave` does the reverse when the `onmouseout` event occurs

```
var hoverActive = false;

var activeImageId = 1;
var activeImage = document.getElementById("img" + activeImageId);

setInterval(function () {
    // Work out which image is next
    var nextImageId = (activeImageId % 3) + 1;
    var nextImage = document.getElementById("img" + nextImageId);

    // Change shown image
    if (!hoverActive) {
        showImage(nextImage);
        hideImage(activeImage);
    }

    //Next image is now active
    activeImage = nextImage;
    activeImageId = nextImageId;
}, 5000);



function onHover(imageName) {
    hoverActive = true;
    var hoverImage = document.getElementById(imageName);
    showHoverImage(hoverImage);
}

function showHoverImage(hoverImage) {
    hideImage(activeImage);
    showImage(hoverImage);
}

function onHoverLeave(imageName) {
    hoverActive = false;
    var hoverImage = document.getElementById(imageName);
    hideHoverImage(hoverImage);
}

function hideHoverImage(hoverImage) {
    hideImage(hoverImage);
    showImage(activeImage);
}


function showImage(docImage) {
    if (docImage) {
        docImage.classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
    }
}
function hideImage(docImage) {
    if (docImage) {
        docImage.classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @p7dxb. Yes, it is working and I like what it has because that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the function and JS code. Is that your ideal?

```js
var activeImageId = 1;
    var nextImageId = 1;

    setInterval(function() {
        nextImageId = nextImageId + 1;

        changeImgByID();
    }, 5000);
    
    function changeImgByID() {
      if (nextImageId < 3) {
            document.getElementById("img" + activeImageId).classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
            document.getElementById("img" + nextImageId).classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
            activeImageId = nextImageId;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("img" + activeImageId).classList.replace("visible", "hidden");
            document.getElementById("img" + nextImageId).classList.replace("hidden", "visible");
            activeImageId = 3;
            nextImageId = 0;
        }
    }
    
    
    // for first image
    function changeImg(val) {
        nextImageId=val;
        changeImgByID();
    }
```

```css
.why-choose-main-container {
        border: 1px solid red;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-details {
        border: 2px solid green;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-details .card {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 570px;
        height: 670px;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img.visible {
        display: block;
    }

    .why-choose-main-container .why-choose-image img.hidden {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="why-choose-main-container">
        <div class="why-choose-details">
            <div class="card img-1" onmouseover="changeImg(1)">
                <h2>why1</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card img-2" onmouseover="changeImg(2)">
                <h2>why2</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card img-3" onmouseover="changeImg(3)">
                <h2>why3</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="why-choose-image">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="img1" id="img1" class="visible">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_girl.jpg" alt="img2" id="img2" class="hidden">
            <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/img_chania.jpg" alt="img3" id="img3" class="hidden">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes this is my idea which I want to draft it

Comment: Second, yes it is working but when I hover the card and remove the cursor, the second JS functionality starts only from the image where I hover the cursor which is not correct. The images should be rotated from where they were, just on hover it should provide the corresponding image of that card and when we remove the hover from that card then the corresponding image of that card should also be moved.